# Did other Star Wars species see into the ultraviolet?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-rebels

I understand from [this](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phase_I_clone_trooper_armor) article on the Star Wars Wiki page that Clone Trooper armor was only white to human eyes, not the Kaminoans who built it (they could see ultraviolet light and so thought it was colored).

Assuming the Kaminoans aren't stupid, this would only make sense if many races can also see into the ultraviolet so **are there many Star Wars races who have ultraviolet vision** and **is the issue of how they view clone trooper armour addressed in any canon?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes (at least in Legends canon).

The Star Wars [wikia page, "Ultraviolet"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultraviolet) covers this:

Defel, Umbarans, Gand, Kaminoans, and Hutts.

(Verpine also, as per @Jeff's comment - Legends canon)

Comment: I'm not sure if Hutts are Disney canon or Legends, the info is from "Star Wars: The Clone Wars: The Visual Guide" and Star Wars: The Clone Wars Character Encyclopedia". Everyone else is from Legengs sources

Comment: Verpine are indicated to be able to in the X-Wing series of Legends novels (specifically, *The Bacta War*).  Ooryl's X-Wing is painted (by the Verpine mechanic) when the Rouges are rouge agents.  Corran comments that Ooryl's X-wing looks very plain, only to be told that 'Zraii tells me that if you can see in UV, it's a masterpiece'.